# Ajax Hover Question

Tags: ajax

I am brand new to AJAX but I feel AJAX is what I need to get this requirement finished. When the user hovers over a link, I need a box to show where they can input their email and name for a newsletter signup. Can someone kindly provide me with what this technique is called in AJAX so I can try to find some tutorials? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a JQuery plugin such as clueTip. You can find demos and documentation on clueTip here: http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/

Try looking at example number 4 on that page, entitled **sticky, with arrows**